# How to manipulate hierarchical breakdown in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Please consider below screenshot

[image: Excel Hierarchy]

We can see that the tasks and corresponding items under it are properly grouped in a tree hierarchy. I wasn't able to figure out how I can manipulate this hierarchy in excel or create one from scratch. Please advise.

Comment: With rows selected, `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`RIGHT` to create a group, and `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`LEFT` to remove a group. Or go into the Data tab, and find the buttons for it.

Comment: Dear pOrinG, is the given hint helps?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Thanks a lot, I got it.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes it helped, thank you.

Comment: Then, @ChristoferWeber should post is as an answer.. and the asker will give a tick. || This will remove this question from "unanswered" question list, and benefit the future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an outline or group, and can be done on both rows and columns. 
For a more technical in-depth explanation, check out the [Office Support page](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff) on the topic (Or google *excel grouping*).

You find the options for this under the **Data** tab:
[image]

But you can also group via the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (add) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (remove) while having the rows or columns selected.

Comment: You can also use the "Subtotals" tool.

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately I don't know. My Excel isn't in english, so I borrowed and modified an image from the web, which already had the arrows in it.